# php javascript permissions problem

Tags: php, javascript, permissions

Kind of a weird problem... not something ive ever run into before.

So, i am using CKeditor, and am creating the upload and browse functions for users to upload and use images in the rich text editor. So, everything works great in firefox, they can upload images, and place them into the rich text editor, and save whatever they are doing to the database.

The problem comes in with IE.

When i try to do the exact same thing in IE (7 or 8), the page returns:

"You have been kicked out from a standard permission violation"

It doesnt load anything, just on a white background, it prints this.

ive broken down to the point that every directory that the script is accessing has 777 permissions just to make sure it isnt something like that... and it doesnt seem like it is the code since it works in firefox.

Honetly, im at a total loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of a network is your test client running on? That message doesn't sound like a standard error.

Comment: And what's the server setup? Is it shared-hosting, or some other sort of pre-packaged hosting, or did you set up the server yourself from scratch?

Comment: You might try packet-sniffing with Wireshark if you're comfortable looking at raw HTTP. Could give you some clues. Maybe there's some tool that integrates more closely with IE also (a parallel to Firebug) but I wouldn't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing IE with lower security levels. Tools->Options->Security. Lower the slider down to the bottom and even try disabling 'Protected Mode'. In the Privacy tab you can have a play around with the level as well. Drag the slider to the bottom to accept all cookies. Don't worry you can just click the 'Default' buttons in each of these tabs to restore your protection.

Also [something else](http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/4209) I just found might help with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just tried it and got same thing.

it doesnt seem like this should be a user level error...

Comment: Just edited my answer with another idea, not sure if you will be alerted to the edit but this comment should anyway.